# How to restore from the backups to a new indices?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am bit confused in restoring the data from the my backup. I have created a backup of my indices with following command:

```
PUT /_snapshot/my_backup
{
  "type": "fs",
  "settings": {
    "location": "D:\\my_backup"
  }
}


PUT /_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_1?wait_for_completion=true
{
  "indices": "customers",
  "ignore_unavailable": true,
  "include_global_state": false
}
```

Then I remove all my indices from my elasticsearch. Now I want to restore from my backup that I had. How can I do? I checked the documentation and I get more confused.

I tried following at the moment

```
POST /_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_1/_restore
{
  "indices": "ecommerce",
  "ignore_unavailable": "true",
  "include_global_state": false,
  "rename_pattern": "ecommerce",
  "rename_replacement": "jal1"
}
```

Any help please. I want to restore from the given backup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to check the indice name of your backup data. In your case try

```
GET http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_backup/_all
```

you can find the indices name provided.

Now you can use your post query with the indices from above query

```
POST /_snapshot/my_backup/snapshot_1/_restore
{
  "indices": "your_indices_name",
  "ignore_unavailable": "true",
  "include_global_state": false,
  "rename_pattern": "your_indices_name",
  "rename_replacement": "your_new_indices_name"
}
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: thank you. I was not aware about indices name. Now it worked . thank you once again